# Close activity without finish

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to dismiss my DialogView on button click but don't want to finish activity.If i use finish() method then activity is finished and further processing is stopped.

Comment: What do you mean `close`?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen close means i don't want to show it like we have dismissAllowingStateLoss() function in DialogFragment which actually dismiss it.

Comment: Then what do you want to show?

Comment: If you are doing a long processing, you should extract the task from your activity to an external class. Consider using MVP or MVVM pattern to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. When a activity is closed (for example: using back button), it is ultimately stopped and destroyed, similar to calling `finish()` method on activity.

Take a look at activity lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc).

If you want something to live beyond activity's lifecycle, you have to use Background Service, Work Manager or something similar.

Comment: but if i call finish() on button click then further processing is stopped. Like in my case coins are not consumed which i purchased using inapp.

Comment: yes, this is the whole point of finish(). it means, you are done with that activity. now you want to destroy it. if you don't want to do so, wait until inapp is done, then call finish()